# onActivityResult() not called on main Activity when new activity started from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, start-activity

I know there are many posts on why onActivityResult() is not called in the Fragment when startActivityForResult() is called from fragment ; but my case is different.

My activity A has a fragment F which starts an activity B for result. The fragment receives the result no problem here. The problem is that when activity A is restarted, it builds its entire view asynchronously using an AsynTask which is called during onResume(). As a result, my fragment F is covered by Activity A.

In my fragment, I start the Activity like this :

```
 startActivityForResult(intent, NewElementFragment.CODE_IMAGE_PATH);
```

So I thought, no worries, I know that onResume() is called after onActivityResult(), so all I need to do is make sure in onActivityResult() that the view will not be created during onResume().

I created a boolean that I set to false during onActivityResult() like this :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //put the NewElementFragment back on top
    if (requestCode == NewElementFragment.CODE_IMAGE_PATH){
        //we set loadinfo to false so that the activity view won't get built 
        this.loadInfo = false;
        Log.d("MainActivity","the loadInfo boolean was set to false");
    }
    //Do default action on result (nothing) so that the result is passed on the the fragments
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

But it did not work because apparently the onActivityResult() was never triggered in my activity A (even though as I said before it is perfectly triggered in my fragment).

So in the end I checked in on Resume if I had an active fragment and if yes, abort the view creation like this :

```
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    /*
     * We check if there is a fragment built that should be visible. If yes, we don't build the view
     */
    NewElementFragment f = (NewElementFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_NEW_ELEMENT_FRAGMENT);
    if (f!=null){
        loadInfo = false;
    }
    //We call the GetProductDetailTask
    if (loadInfo) new GetProductDetailTask(pId).execute();      
}
```

It works but I find it quite ugly. Could someone tell me why the onActivityResult() is never called in my activity A ?

Or if someone has a better solution to make sure that my fragment is not covered by my activity when it is restarted ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting activity must implement some Interface, and you must call it from your fragment. In this Interface realization you can call another Activity via `startActivityForResult()`. In this case you'll success in `onActivityResult()` processing.